# GL_APPLE_clip_distance in opengl es 2.0

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

The documentation on GL_APPLE_clip_distance states that it is supported on both ES2.0 and ES3.0.  I am trying to get it to work on devices that don't support ES3.0.

The shader files have the #extension at the top of the file.

```
#extension GL_APPLE_clip_distance : require
```

The shader files compile without errors indicating that they have no problems with the syntax.  I have loaded an ES2 context.  However the first time I attempt to enable a clip Plane as in;

```
glEnable ( GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0_APPLE )
```

All the subsequent glDrawArray calls fail with the error.  The specified operation is invalid for the current OpenGL state.  The GLKView renders black, supposedly because all the the draw calls are now failing.

Interestingly even if I disable the state;

```
glDisable ( GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0_APPLE )
```

all the subsequent draw calls still continue to fail;.  So the very first call to glEnable( GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0_APPLE ) triggers some irrecoverable state that can't be undone.

Any tips / suggestions on workarounds would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working this issue for a couple of days and only a half hour after finally posting to stackoverflow it got fixed.  Here is the answer in case it will be of help to others too.

I changed the the floating precision from lowp to highp.  Somehow lowp works well for 3.0 but not so well for es 2.0.

```
varying lowp float gl_ClipDistance[4];
```

changed to:

```
varying highp float gl_ClipDistance[4];
```